# How can I get Auto-reloading to work on Play 2.8.x?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I've looked through StackOverflow and the internet to try to find an answer to this, and tested them all but somehow it doesn't work. My Terminal says this when starting the sbt application:

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
```

However, it's not true. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA with the Scala plugin installed, and I've tried everything with Eclipse as well.

This is what my `build.sbt` looks like:

```
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0" % Test
```

Does anybody happen to have any solution to this? I've tried adding the "play-watch" library dependency, did not work. I've tried adding the "run" configuration to the IntelliJ configurations as an sbt task, but neither that worked, and a ton of other small things that I found around.

Anybody who happens to have a solution to this?

EDIT: This is on OSX

Comment: Windows/linux/Mac?

Comment: What happens when you try to open http://localhost:9000/ first time? It compiles and returns proper site but does not recompile on change or does not compile at all?

Comment: This is on Mac OSX, it compiles and works, but every time I'm changing the code, I need to update it manually to see the changes  -> Refresh Chrome and localhost:9000.

Comment: What do you mean "update it manually"? You need to press enter and then call `run` again to force recompile?

Comment: Same problem on ubuntu 20.04. Neither from "Play" config of intelllij, nor from sbt console (sbt ~run). I cant get to recompile automatically